# Neo4j Java API, how to narrow search results?

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying to do a query on the graph of events.  I search by name and a date range.  I'm not sure what the most efficient way is to do this using the Java API.

I am currently using an index like so: -

```
Index<Node> searchIndex = graphDb.index().forNodes("event-name-desc-search",  MapUtil.stringMap(IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene", "type", "fulltext","to_lower_case", "true" ));

PagingIterator<Node> neoResult = new PagingIterator<Node>(searchIndex.query("name", searchTerm).iterator(), pageSize) ; 

Iterator<Node> resultPage = neoResult.nextPage(); 

while(resultPage.hasNext()){
   ** Do Stuff**
}
```

I don't know how to apply the date range filter without iterating around every single result.  Is there a more sensible way of doing it?

Comment: Can you create new index with filter conditions?

Comment: I've given up and went down the gremlin route, seems to be a lot more efficient